# Facing 500 Internal Server Error with "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects"

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, opencart

My project is combination of Laravel and Opencart. The folder structure as follows:

```
public_html
- mainlyvegan
- .htaccess
```

the content of the htaccess is a follows :-

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mainlyvegan.com$ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainlyvegan/ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mainlyvegan/$1 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mainlyvegan.com$ 
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mainlyvegan/index.php [L]
```

The mainlyvegan folder contains the following  files

```
App
Http
-----
shop
.htaccess
```

with subdomain we access shop/upload/index.php (store.mainlyvegan.com)

it is working fine. but when I try to access its shop/upload/admin/index.php (store.mainlyvegan.com/admin) it is throwing error. I check error_log. it shows the following error

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Best thing to tackle such issues is to enable rewrite logging in your http servers host configuration, raise the error level and learn about what is _really_ going on inside your rewrite engine.